# Work when you work only in even or odd months

Tags: meaning

How do English people call the kind of work when you work the first month then you stay home for the second month then you work the third month then you stay home the fourth month and so on?
I thought it was something like 'month by month job' but it did not.
Thank you

Comment: This is unheard of in England.  So there is no idiomatic expression for it.

Comment: @JamesK - I wonder if the OP made up the example to illustrate the idea of alternation, so that someone here would supply the right word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working alternate months is the only way I can think of describing this unusual arrangement, or maybe informally 'one month on, one month off'.